# How to detect nested fling stopped in CoordinatorLayout.Behavior?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout

How to detect if nested fling stopped entirely using CoordinatorLayout.Behavior?
There is no such api which can give me callback when recycler view fling entirely stops.

Comment: Can't you achieve the same with `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`?

Comment: There is no method like onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)  in CoordinatorLayout.Behavior which can give me scrollState. There is one method called onStopNestedScroll but it's getting called before list entirely stops.

Comment: I meant `onScrollChanged()` for `RecyclerView`

Comment: Thanks for responding, basically I am doing FAB animations inside class extending FloatingActionButton.Behavior called ScrollAwareFABBehavior, how can I check SCROLL_STATE_IDLE  of RecyclerView in this class, moreover this class is passed as layout_behaviour to FAB.

Answer (score 6):

I started down this rabbit hole while trying to hide a [Floating Action Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) (FAB) when a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) was being scrolled.  The *proper* way to do this according to multiple [sources](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons#using-coordinatorlayout) is to extend [FloatingActionButton.Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html), override the `onStartNestedScroll` and `onStopNestedScroll` methods, and hook your behavior up to the FAB, e.g. `app:layout_behavior="com.justingarrick.ui.ScrollAwareFabBehavior"`.  This works for normal (slow) scroll events, but `onStopNestedScroll` is not called when a fling ends.

Currently, there seem to be a number of open [issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=fling) with flinging and scroll behaviors; the workaround for me was to implement an `OnScrollListener` for my RecyclerView and just change the state of the FAB programmatically, e.g.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Bind(R.id.account_list) RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Bind(R.id.button_fab) FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accounts, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
                    fab.hide(); // or hideFab(), see below
                else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                    fab.show(); // or showFab(), see below
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: This works correctly 99% of the time, but if you use the `show()` and `hide()` methods from version 22.2.1 of the design library, you'll run into problems when you try to scroll up at the top of your RecyclerView or down at the bottom of your RecyclerView because the recycler view is switching states from `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` to `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` so quickly that it creates a race condition in `FloatingActionButtonHoneycombMr1#show()`.  So, to fix this (sigh), you either need to switch to `setVisibility()` calls if you don't care about the animations, or re-implement the animations without the race condition, e.g.

```
private void hideFab() {
     fab.animate().scaleX(0.0F).scaleY(0.0F).alpha(0.0F).setDuration(200L).setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator()).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
             fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
     });
 }

 private void showFab() {
     fab.animate().scaleX(1.0F).scaleY(1.0F).alpha(1.0F).setDuration(200L).setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator()).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at least I am not alone who faced this issue.

Comment: Brillant simple solution! I needed to show the FAB only when a specific view in the scroll view was visible and hide it when that view was out of screen. With the Behavior, it was impossible to manage the flings... With the scroll listener it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I use ScrollerCompat with method ScrollerCompat.fling(..) to handle intermediate states of scrolling. So I know when scrolling is ends.

```
@Override
public boolean onNestedFling(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final AppBarLayout child, final View target, final float velocityX, final float velocityY, final boolean consumed) {
    final int scrollY = target.getScrollY();
    final double distance = mFlingHelper.getSplineFlingDistance(velocityY);

    fling(
            child,
            (int) distance + scrollY,
            velocityY,
            scrollY);

    return super.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
}

private void fling(final View pChild, final int pMaxOffset, final float pVelocityY, final int pStartY) {
    stopFling(pChild);
    mIsFlingRunning = true;

    if (mScroller == null) {
        mScroller = ScrollerCompat.create(mContext);
    }

    mScroller.fling(
        0, pStartY, // current
        0, Math.round(pVelocityY), // velocity.
        0, 0, // x
        0, pMaxOffset); // y

    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        mFlingRunnable = new FlingRunnable(pChild);
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(pChild, mFlingRunnable);
    }

}

private void stopFling(final View pChild) {
    if (mFlingRunnable != null) {
        pChild.removeCallbacks(mFlingRunnable);
        mFlingRunnable = null;
    }
}




private class FlingRunnable implements Runnable {

     private final View mView;

     FlingRunnable(final View pView) {
         mView = pView;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         if (mView != null && mScroller != null) {
             if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
                 mIsFlingRunning = true;
                 // Post ourselves so that we run on the next animation
                 ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(mAppBarLayout, this);
             }
         } else {
             mIsFlingRunning = false;
         }
     }
 }
```